# Identify and label groups in SQL based on value that signals group start

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, gaps-and-islands

I'm using SQL Server and have been searching through gaps and islands problems but I can't quite match them up with my exact issue.

I want to group a dataset and label the groups but each group starts with a field having a specific value. There is no value that denotes the group ending. The data looks like this:

| Description | CustomerID | CategoryID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Initial | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-17 |
| Follow up | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-18 |
| Follow up | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-19 |
| Initial | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-23 |
| Follow up | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-24 |
| Initial | 1 | 2 | 2022-08-19 |
| Follow up | 1 | 2 | 2022-08-20 |
| Initial | 2 | 1 | 2022-08-17 |
| Follow up | 2 | 1 | 2022-08-18 |

The dataset above is ordered by CustomerID, then by the CategoryID, then by the dates. The groupings I'm looking for begin with an "Initial" description and end on the final "Follow up" before the next Initial for that given categoryID and CustomerID. The 6th row of this table is an obvious new group because the category changes and the 8th is obvious because the customer changes. But I also want to identify the 4th row as the start of a new group, recognising that the 1st group ends on the 3rd row. Output should look like this:

| GroupID | Description | CustomerID | CategoryID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Initial | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-17 |
| 1 | Follow up | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-18 |
| 1 | Follow up | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-19 |
| 2 | Initial | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-23 |
| 2 | Follow up | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-24 |
| 3 | Initial | 1 | 2 | 2022-08-19 |
| 3 | Follow up | 1 | 2 | 2022-08-20 |
| 4 | Initial | 2 | 1 | 2022-08-17 |
| 4 | Follow up | 2 | 1 | 2022-08-18 |

2 is a new group because another Initial has occurred. 3 is a new group for the same reason AND it's a different CategoryID. 4 is a new group because Initial has occurred AND it's a different customerID.

I'd appreciate any help you can provide or point to a resource that might help. I'm not convinced that a gaps and islands approach is the most optimum way to achieve this. I'm not grouping by jumping gaps and starting a new group. However, if I'm misunderstood and this can be solved as a gaps and islands problem then please let me know. Many thanks.

Edit: Apologies, the Initial description is important but changes in customer or category are of equal importance when grouping. The solution from The Impaler is very simple and identifies new groups based on appearance of Initial but there are some cases where there is no Initial used for a specific customer and category. Is there a way to start a new group ID either if the Initial description is used OR if the customer or category change? The issue I had with The Impaler's answer is that the next row can change customer but remain part of the same group since no Initial was identified.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Gaps & Islands problem. You can just find the `'Initial'` entries and consider those start a new group.

You can do:

```
select
  t.*,
  sum(case when description = 'Initial' then 1 else 0 end) 
    over(order by customerid, categoryid, date) as groupid
from t
order by customerid, categoryid, date
```

Result:

```
 Description  CustomerID  CategoryID  Date        groupid 
 ------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ------- 
 Initial      1           1           2022-08-17  1       
 Follow up    1           1           2022-08-18  1       
 Follow up    1           1           2022-08-19  1       
 Initial      1           1           2022-08-23  2       
 Follow up    1           1           2022-08-24  2       
 Initial      1           2           2022-08-19  3       
 Follow up    1           2           2022-08-20  3       
 Initial      2           1           2022-08-17  4       
 Follow up    2           1           2022-08-18  4
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=81e484c56fbdf21d30f1c16e01d91b49).

**EDIT**: In case there are no "initial" entries for a customer. You can peek at the previous row using `LAG()` and then decide if this is a new group. For example:

```
select
  x.*,
  sum(case when description = 'Initial' or customerid <> prev_cust
           then 1 else 0 end) 
    over(order by customerid, categoryid, date) as groupid
from (
  select t.*,
    lag(customerid) over(order by customerid, categoryid, date) as prev_cust
  from t
) x
order by customerid, categoryid, date
```

See [db<>fiddle 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=201be2cb0fb9e7401762f4820dfd1769).

Comment: Thank you, I was sure it was a simpler solution than gaps and islands (which I've used before). It's much simpler than I expected and you explained clearly. Thank you.

Comment: The only issue remaining is that the Description is a new addition to the dataset so there are Follow Up rows that aren't associated with any Initial. In my testing I saw it work correctly grouping a customer and category together on an Initial but when it hit another customer that doesn't have an Initial entry it counted those in the same group as the previous customer since no new Initial was found. I guess I need to figure out a way to change the group id when initial appears OR it's a new customer or category.

Comment: In that case I can see those "follow up" entries in the group `0`.

Comment: I've added a customer 3 to the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=88b238889f67ce4bd3883be24ba9d020

Comment: I could look in advance for customers with no initial and flag them to be ignored and figure out another way to group them I guess

Comment: @Ann See new solution.

Comment: Not sure what makes it not a gaps-and-islands problem, it's just a particular variation of it